# How to drop by selecting rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have df like this

```
A  B  C
1  a  X
2  b  Y
3  c  Z
```

I would like to drop `b` in column`B`
Therefore my desired result is like this

```
A B C
1 a X
3 c Z
```

Are there any way to achieve this ?

I tried like `df.drop("b")` . But it seems we need to specify columns..

Thanks

Comment: df1 = df.loc[~(df['B'] == 'b')] ... this should work? Am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'''
A  B  C
1  a  X
2  b  Y
3  c  Z
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df1 = df.loc[~(df['B'] == 'b')]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  X
2  3  c  Z
```