# Pandas copy an array to csv - error message; *** ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: pandas, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

Hi I'm trying to save different numpy arrays to csv files using the following command in a looped script

`df = pd.DataFrame(arr)` - it fails here

`df.astype(str).to_excel`(outputFile)

It works fine for an array of the following shape and dtype

of (8L,) & [('add','

however when I try it with an array with the following shape and dtype

of (13L, 4L) & [('add', '

I get the following message

```
*** ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

So the shape of the first csv file id 2 columns by 8 rows and ideally I'd like the 2nd csv to have a format of 8 columns by 13 rows

FN

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839973/constructing-pandas-dataframe-from-values-in-variables-gives-valueerror-if-usi

Comment: When I try the following 

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=[0])

the message I get is

*** Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output in a copy pastable format?

Comment: Thanks, how can I attach files?

Comment: Please check this documentation once: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, one quick example could be a question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928103/how-to-drop-by-selecting-rows-in-pandas/61928178#61928178

Comment: apologies and thanks for bearing with me but I'm just after noticing that some text isn't coming up in the main question. this is the shape and the dtype of the numpy array I am trying to save to csv - (13L, 4L) & [('add', '<f8'), ('mul', '<f8')])

Comment: This is the shape and dtype of the file that works when I save it to csv - (8L,) & [('add','<f8'), ('mul', '<f8')])